# MySqlConnection.Open hangs on indefinitely

Tags: c#, mysql, xampp

I'm creating a desktop application that connects to a SQL database. I'm having trouble connecting to the database for some reason, the connection hangs on indefinitely without giving an error (does no timeout like it should). I'm using XAMPP for my database. I've Googled the problem extensively I have tried for example changing the connection string and turning off the firewall.

Here is my code:

```
string connectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=typewrite;Uid=root;Pwd=";

    public int signIn(string username, string password)
    {
        int signinNum = -1;
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open(); // here is the problem
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                return signinNum;
            }

            using (MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                try
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT 'USER_id' WHERE USER_name = @name AND pass = @passw";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", username);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@passw", password);
                    MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        signinNum = reader.GetInt32(0);
                    }
                }
                catch (MySqlException ex)
                {
                    return signinNum;
                }
            }
        }
        return signinNum;
    }
```

I have tried diffrent variations of this without prevail. I know I should use mutli thredding so it won't stop my application how ever I would like to get a connection to the database before I go any further.

And on top of that I have done something like this before and it connected with out a problem.

Comment: Never ever store passwords as plain text

Comment: Doesn't really address the question as asked, but I most certainly agree.

Comment: I know I am not intending to store a password in plane text, this is code is only there to test the connection.

Answer (score 0):

I found out why it would not connect, I had to create a password for the xampp database and put that in my connection string.